# Filter and exclude a level in stat_density2d_filled

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, density-plot

I have code and data like that to map some locations in the USA:

```
library(sf)

library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
Latitude = round(runif(5000, 31, 46), digits = 5)
Longitude = round(runif(5000, -120, -80), digits = 5)
df = data.frame(Latitude, Longitude) 


world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
usa = filter(world,admin =="United States of America")

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "blue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
   default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    ))+stat_density2d_filled(data = df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill=(..level..),
         alpha = (..level..)),  geom = "polygon")
```

I have the output like this:[image]

I am looking to exclude some levels like (0,0002,0004], and (0,0004,0006]. Additionally, I would like to manually color the levels. I have this code   `scale_fill_manual(values = c("khaki1", "khaki2", "khaki2", "orange", "orange", "red", "red", "red", "red"))` , however would like to use  `scale_fill_gradientn` and  color palettes in the RColorBrewer package like YlOrRd.

Comment: When I try to run your code it can't find `usa` dataset

Comment: Oh sorry I edit it now.

Comment: You can improve your questions by using the reprex package to ensure that your code is reproducible. It catches mistakes I make all the time, especially forgetting to include packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the usa basemap layer, but does this do what you want with your density layer?

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
Latitude = round(runif(5000, 31, 46), digits = 5)
Longitude = round(runif(5000, -120, -80), digits = 5)
df = data.frame(Latitude, Longitude) 



breaks <- seq(from = 0.0006, to = 0.0020, by = 0.0002)

# Plot
ggplot() +
  # geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "blue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-119, -74),
    ylim = c(22, 51),
    default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    )) +
  stat_density2d_filled(data = df, 
                        aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, 
                            fill = after_stat(level), 
                            alpha = after_stat(level)),  
                        geom = "polygon",
                        breaks = breaks) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Appreciate your time. This is exactly what I am looking for.